# View buildings in MapBox

Tags: zooming, mapbox

I want to show all the buildings in my little village (fill in black color). I see them when I zoom in to the village (zoom=16), but when I zoom out, to 14 or 12, I lost the building and can't see them anymore:

**First picture is zoom in, second is zoom out without buildings**:

[image: First picture is zoom in, second is zoom out without buildings]

Answer (score 0):

Just find zoom level at which buildings appear, save geometry and for bigger/smaller zoom levels simply scale building geometry proportionally.